# Extending class hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods, abstraction

I have an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public double CommonMethodForAllSubClasses(double parameter)
    {
        //common implementation
        return 0;
    }

    public abstract double MethodThatMustBeDefinedInSubClasses(double parameter);
}
```

And a class hierarchy under it.

I want to make, in another assembly, an Extension class for Base class and its subclasses. I thought to do it with a static class with a methods which receive as parameter:

```
public static Method(this BaseClass, ...)
```

But I want this static Method to be defined for all subclasses from BaseClass. I know I can't do a static abstract method but I want to avoid to implement these methods in the class itself... And it would be very good that the compiler "tells me" that these methods must be redefined for sub-classes.

Comment: If you want the compiler to remind you, you'll have to use abstract methods or interfaces. You can create extension methods for different child types, but that will only work as expected when the types are known at compile-time. Perhaps the best approach here is to combine extension methods (high-level, type-independent logic) with abstract methods (low-level, type-specific code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want this static Method to be defined for all subclasses from BaseClass.

Your extension method would be callable from instance of derived class. But I guess that's not what you meant.

> And it would be very good that the compiler "tells me" that these methods must be redefined for sub-classes.

Implementing it as a regular `abstract` method on the base class is the only way to achieve that.

Comment: After a few days researching I agree with you... Its a pitty that C# doesn't offer it somehow. So could I extend a basic architecture and be sure that every class must be defined in these extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected abstract void MethodThatMustBeDefinedInSubClasses();
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void MethodThatMustBeDefinedInSubClasses()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do");
    }
}

public static class BaseClassExtensions
{
    public static void DoExtension(this BaseClass foo) { }

    public static void DoExtension(this ChildClass bar) {}
}
```

You can specify the extension method for every derived class in the hierarchy and provide a specific implementation for it.

About the "compiler telling you" about a extension method, I think that's not possible, because the extension method is just "syntactic sugar". The extension method can be used like this:

```
var foo = new BaseClass();
foo.DoExtension();
```

But actually is just like a normal static class:

```
var foo = new BaseClass();
BaseClassExtensions.DoSomething(foo);
```

And the compiler cannot warning you that you should make a static class with a method that should accept a specific type.